# Tax code not returning % for US but returning % for UK

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When I tried to get TaxCode for US based company in Quickbooks, it's returning data (GST) but not its percentage.

When I tried to get TaxCode for UK based company in Quickbooks, it's returning data with the percentage like GST - 18%

Is it a bug in Quickbooks API?

I have tried in API explorer as well -

https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=TaxCode

I am using Consolibyte PHP API -

```
            $response = $QuickBooksHelper->init($QuickBooksConfigObj);

            $TaxCodeService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_TaxCode();

            $taxcodes = $TaxCodeService->query($response['context'], $response['realm'], "SELECT * FROM TaxCode");
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you can show us?

Comment: I am using consolibyte API - https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php Added my code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Used TaxRate to get the tax information.

https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=TaxRate